# How do I create a shortcut for a find and replace command in vim?

Tags: vim, mysql, regex

I have a vim (well, sed really) find and replace pattern I use for resetting the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property in mySQL `CREATE TABLE` statements:

> :%s/AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*/AUTO_INCREMENT=1/g

I use this command often, and would like to create a shortcut in vim.  I know I will have to edit my .vimrc, but I can't figure out the `cmap` syntax.

My end goal is to be able to run

> :reset-auto-increment

And run the above find and replace globally throughout the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that goal, I think a user-defined command would be better than a cmap. See

```
:help 40.2
:help user-commands
```

Vim requires that user-defined commands begin with an upper-case letter and contain only letters and digits. No hyphens. So your command will have to be something like ResetAutoIncrement.

```
command ResetAutoIncrement %s/AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*/AUTO_INCREMENT=1/g
```

You can avoid typing the whole command name each time you use it by typing just the first few characters, then hitting Tab.